# pubring.gpg and secring.gpg are missing after key generation

Tags: macos, encryption, gnupg

I'm a newbie to GnuPG. I was following the instruction ["Generating a Key Pair"](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/working-with-pgp-signatures.html). And finally I do not see neither `pubring.gpg` nor `secring.gpg` in my `~/.gnupg` directory:

```
chriss-MBP:.gnupg andrej$ ls -la
total 24
drwx------  10 andrej  staff   340 Feb  5 23:20 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 44 andrej  staff  1496 Feb  5 23:17 ..
srwxr-xr-x   1 andrej  staff     0 Feb  5 23:19 S.gpg-agent
-rw-------   1 andrej  staff     0 Feb  5 23:17 dirmngr.conf
-rw-------   1 andrej  staff     0 Feb  5 23:17 gpg.conf
drwx------   3 andrej  staff   102 Feb  5 23:20 openpgp-revocs.d
drwx------   4 andrej  staff   136 Feb  5 23:20 private-keys-v1.d
-rw-r--r--   1 andrej  staff  1375 Feb  5 23:20 pubring.kbx
-rw-------   1 andrej  staff    32 Feb  5 23:17 pubring.kbx~
-rw-------   1 andrej  staff  1280 Feb  5 23:20 trustdb.gpg
```

What am I doing wrong?

The key is seemed to be generated:

```
chriss-MBP:~ andrej$ gpg2 --list-keys
/Users/andrej/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
--------------------------------
pub   rsa2048/E40D351A 2016-02-05 [SC]
uid         [ultimate] My Name <my@email.com>
sub   rsa2048/EA645178 2016-02-05 [E]
```

I'm using GnuPG version 2.1.11:

```
chriss-MBP:.gnupg andrej$ gpg2 --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.11
libgcrypt 1.6.4
```

My OS X version:

```
chriss-MBP:.gnupg andrej$ sw_vers -productVersion 
10.10.5
```

Comment: This is a question about general tool usage and off topic on Stack Overflow. I voted for migration to Super User, please have a look at the [FAQ] next time posting a question and verify which site it fits.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

GnuPG 2.1 (and upwards) switched to a new keyring format with better performance. For newly generated keyrings, the keys are stored in the `pubring.kbx` file. Another change was merging public and private keyrings, that's why there is no additional `secring.kbx`.

With other words: the files changed, but you're not missing anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and sorry for placing post in the wrong place.

Comment: To clarify: does the pubring.kbx hold only public keys, or both public and private??

Comment: GnuPG 2.1 merged the private keyring into the public keyring, both for the old keyring and new keybox formats. So yes: `pubring.kbx` holds both public and private keys.

Comment: Thanks. Here is a source on that: https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html

Comment: @JensErat so how do i extract the public key and private key out of this `.kbx` file. I tried `gpg --export > ~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg` it worked but if i try `gpg --export-secret-keys > ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg` it seems no private key extracted.

Answer (score 6):

In case you need the `secring.gpg`, run the following command:

```
gpg --keyring secring.gpg --export-secret-keys > ~/.gnupg/secring.gpg
```

Comment: Thanks man, you saved my day! I needed this file for some old API for publishing, and now everything works!